# Change TextView Of Another Layout File

Tags: android, android-studio

How I can change the TextView by ID of another LayOut file?

Here's code: https://pastebin.com/BDs4H3uE

Here's the scenario:

I've created a drawer Menu, here's the Layout XML:

activity_main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="277dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    />
```

drawer_menu.xml inside the menu folder [The Slider Menu]

right_menu.xml inside the menu folder [Right Side Menu Containing Notification Icon]

Inside right_menu.xml, I've added the layout file:

```
<item
        android:title="Notifications"
        android:id="@+id/notification_icon"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/bell"/>
```

The bell layout file contains the bell icon and a TextView with id (@+id/notification_num) showing the notification count in numbers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/right_menu"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/hotlist_bell"
        android:src="@drawable/bell_icon"
        ></ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/hotlist_bell"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/hotlist_bell"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hotlist_bell"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/hotlist_bell"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_square"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Problem:

I want to change the TextView text dynamically from the MainActivity.java file. E.g the text of @+id/notification_num

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Right Side Menu"? The options menu? Another `<NavigationView>` menu? Something else?

Comment: Yes, another menu, Drawer menu is what slides from Left to Right and right_menu is a menu containing notification icon and user_dp.

Comment: Well, if it is indeed a `NavigationView`, it should be something like: `rightNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.notification_icon).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.notification_num)`.

Comment: rightNavigationView is the ID of the right side navigation menu?

Comment: In that example, it's specifically a `NavigationView` variable. If the `<NavigationView>` element in the XML has that ID, then that's fine, too.

Comment: But the problem is that I've designed the notification icon on another layout file called bell.xml, inside that there's an TextView and I need to change that dynamically. Something like Inflator but I'm not able to figure it out...

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is, exactly. If `right_menu` is the `app:menu` for another `<NavigationView>` that you have on the right side, then you simply need to use `findViewById()` to get that `NavigationView` in code, an then the line I gave above should give you that `TextView`.

Comment: Here's the code to understand what I've done so far: https://pastebin.com/BDs4H3uE

Comment: In that setup, the `right_menu` menu is being used as the options menu. It's slightly different for that, which is why I asked that. In `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, after the `inflate()` call, it would be something like `textView = menu.findItem(R.id.notification_icon).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.notification_num)`. Of course, you can split that up a little, if you prefer.

Comment: I've tried this code: https://pastebin.com/mg4SGudY but app crashes,

Comment: You can't do that in `onCreate()`. Either do it in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, as I explained above, or in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, if you'll need to change it periodically while that `Activity` is open.

Comment: Got it, workimg, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I wanted was to change the TextView of menu item, here's the code that helped me:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.right_menu,menu);
    TextView textView = (TextView) menu.findItem(R.id.notification_icon).getActionView().findViewById(R.id.hotlist_hot);
    textView.setText("11");

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```